# Don't duplicate content in a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, duplicates

I enter informations in a database from a JSON fetched every 15mn.
But i don't want to duplicate content each time the JSON is parsed.
I can compare the entries by a a "link" column.

The solution i have is something like that :

```
$query="SELECT link FROM guests WHERE link=$comparison LIMIT 1";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

if ($row < 1 ){
ENTER THE NEW CONTENT
}
```

But I think this is not the best solution.
It is not very light to do that at every turn right?

Thanks.

Comment: Set a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on the column `link` in your table `guests`. Then, when you are parsing JSON and saving it in the database, use `INSERT IGNORE INTO` or `REPLACE INTO`.

Comment: If you don't want duplicate content, one option would be to make the column as UNIQUE. There are other solutions am sure.

Comment: @DaveChen also `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: Thanks to all of you ! Dave, it seems that i can's set a unique constraint on this column necause i already have a primary key on the id field. Is it normal ?

Comment: Please set the unique constraint on the link column. For example, `ALTER TABLE guests ADD UNIQUE (link)`. If the table already has duplicates, then simply use `ALTER IGNORE` instead to remove all the duplicates within the table.

Comment: Ok, but i have this message : "debug : #1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'lien' used in key specification without a key length{"success":false,"error":"

Comment: Maybe more literate and clearer will be 
   
    `if (mysqli_num_rows($row) == 0) {
        ENTER THE NEW CONTENT
    }`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned prior, your best option here is to use a UNIQUE constraint on your 'link' column.

As far as how to insert a row without first checking the row count of your "does-this-exist" query, the way to go would be:

INSERT IGNORE
This will not insert a row with a duplicate 'link' column. However, it will not throw an error, so be aware that duplicates will fail silently.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems impossible to use a unique constrain on the link solumns, because, my id column is a primary key. Right ?

Comment: It's possible to have multiple unique columns within a table. You're allowed to have both a primary key and a unique constraint.

Comment: Thanks John. I have not yet found the solution. But I just realized that text fields can not be set to Unique. So i can use the Unique solution for my case...